# war file not deploying in Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, war, deploying

I have a war file which i want to deploy in my system on tomcat .What I've so far is
1.Shutdown my tomcat from cmd.

2.Set environment variables "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51" and "%CATALINA_HOME%/bin" .

3.Set appBase="webapps" ,autoDeploy="true", name="localhost", unpackWARs="true"
in server.xml .

4.Copy the war file into "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\MyProject" .

5.Restart tomcat using cmd.

```
                        After doing all this steps the log I got from catalina.log is
```

"INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\MyProject
Jun 07, 2017 4:50:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\MyProject has finished in 188 ms
Jun 07, 2017 4:50:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory"

```
                       It seems like MyProject is deployed without any error but when I try to access it using the url http://localhost:8084/MyProject/ the browser shows
```

HTTP Status 404 - /MyProject/

type Status report

message /MyProject/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
                            My tomcat is running fine when i go to the url http://localhost:8084(8080 is the default port of tomcat but i changed it to 8084)

Comment: Can you provide your project structure

Comment: thanks for your interest @utsavanand . I got the solution from the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 4.Copy the war file into "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\MyProject" .

You should put your war file to C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\ instead.

Tomcat will then automatically unpack (into a directory named after a war file) and deploy it.

If you create a webapp sub-folder yourself, Tomcat thinks that it is an already unpacked webapp (with a single .war binary file inside it), and deploys it, but as it is virtually empty (aside the .war archive file), you get 404 while trying to access it.

Comment: Correct.  If the name is MyProject.war, then the context name will be http://localhost:8080/MyProject